# Reading a file from external SD card giving fileNotFoundException open failed: ENOENT android Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to read a file from external SD card in android Marshmallow 6.0.1 and want to convert in byte, but it is giving fileNotFoundException. But my same code is working for 6.0 and below. My code is as follows:

```
private String convertFileToByteArray(File file) { //file path as: /storage/emulated/0/abc.doc
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {

            File f=new File(file.toString());
            Log.e("File EXISTs: >>",""+f.exists());

           //getting error in this line,giving fileNotFoundException
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

            Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Can any one suggest me what's wrong i am doing here.
PS: I am giving runtime permissions also.

Comment: you must give permission from application by code of permission for 6.0

Answer (score 1):

In marshmallow use this code for external storage in try block.

```
public  boolean isexternalStoragePermissionGranted() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {

        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}
else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: can't we do with set targetSdkVersion as 22 without asking runtime permissions. If no then please explain.

Comment: Amit blow SDKVersion22 or below sdk not want to do verify permission

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

use permission

Please go through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))